# Connecting to remote MongoDB - SSH issues

Tags: linux, mongodb, ssh

I'm trying to connect to a remote MongoDB server over using a GUI, and also via the command line but think I'm having issues with the SSH part.

I believe there's something configured on the remote server that's not allowing the SSH tunnel and I'm not sure where to start looking, bear in mind that I don't yet have sudo access.

I can connect to the remote server using standalone SSH tools no problem (putty, ssh via command line, winscp), but trying to connect to MongoDB fails

I've tried creating a tunnel between my machine and the remote machine

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/private-key -N -L27018:localhost:27017 user@site.com -vvv
```

Then on my machine I run the following

```
$ mongo --port 27018
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27018/test
2017-08-08T08:28:36.152+0000 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
2017-08-08T08:28:36.153+0000 Error: DBClientBase::findN: transport error: 127.0.0.1:27018 ns: admin.$cmd query: { whatsmyuri: 1 } at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148
exception: connect failed
```

With the tunnel log showing this

```
debug1: Connection to port 27018 forwarding to localhost port 27017 requested.
debug2: fd 6 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug3: receive packet: type 92
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
debug2: channel 2: zombie
debug2: channel 2: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 27018 for localhost port 27017, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 41672 to 127.0.0.1 port 27018, nchannels 3
debug3: channel 2: status: The following connections are open:
```

As a test I setup a vagrant machine with mongodb on it and was able to connect from my host machine via the command line and via a GUI.

Are there anything specific configuration variables that might prevent me from connecting via SSH?

The remote server has these settings but toggling them on the vagrant machine didn't make a difference, I was still able to connect

```
#bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Issues about setting up SSH Tunnelling are better off asked on either [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com) or [superuser.com](https://superuser.com). No there is nothing about MongoDB itself that blocks using SSH tunnels and the issues are entirely to do with your configuration and this is not a programming issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

The ssh server that you're connecting to is configured not to permit TCP forwarding. If you have access to reconfigure the server, and assuming this is the OpenSSH server, refer to the documentation for the [AllowTcpForwarding](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#AllowTcpForwarding) configuration option.